# C# - Draw picture from List<int>[]

Tags: c#

I have to draw a picture from integer values.

```
List<int>[] channelData
```

In channelData are 5081 arrays with 2048 values each.
Because there is only one integer per pixel (between 0-1000), the picture is black/white.

This is my code to draw the picture pixel by pixel:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(channelData[0].Count, channelData.Length);
        for (int y = 0; y < channelData.Length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < channelData[y].Count; x++) {
                int myColor = (channelData[y].ElementAt(x) * 255) / 1000;
                myBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(myColor, myColor, myColor));
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;
```

The code works, but only if I let draw 4 rows. If I let draw more, I get an exception:

```
"System.ArgumentException" in System.Drawing.dll
```

I there a better way to draw the picture?

Comment: Which exactly line of code throws this exception and what are arguments of method being called at that time? I suspect it is something wrong with color value. Have you tried to debug your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things could cause this exception:

- `myColor` is either below `0` or above `255` and `Color.FromArgb()` throws the exception. Make sure the range of your data really is `[0; 1000]`.
- Either `x` or `y` exceeds the image dimensions and `Bitmap.SetColor()` throws the exception. Most likely it is `x`, which relates to the second dimension of your data structure (the length of the `List<int>`s). Make sure that each `List<int>` is as long as the first `List<int>` in the array `channelData`, since you use this one's length to create the `Bitmap`.

To be sure you always have sufficient image dimensions, try creating your `Bitmap` like so:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var myBitmap = new Bitmap(channelData.Max(l => l.Count), channelData.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks, there are 4 values over 1000....the documentation says there are only values with max. 1000. For this reason I did not checked it.